# jQuery - Check if specific word in text box has been deleted and change class of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox which a user can type in, and below is a list of tags which can be clicked.

When a user clicks a tag, it is entered in the textbox and the tag is highlighted by changing the class. When a user clicks the same tag again, it deletes the tag from the textbox and removes the class from the tag so it is back to its original, non-highlighted state.

This creates a problem where if the user deletes the tag them themselves, it still stays highlighted in our collection of tags at the bottom. Is there any way to check whether specific text has been deleted from the textbox so we can remove the class from the tag? I was thinking some jQuery but I don't know where to start

The code for the box and tags is :

```
<div class="container">
  <textarea id="ReplyBox" placeholder="Give some more information..." class='message-content-box'></textarea>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tags">
    <a href="#" class="mytag">#tag1</a>
    <a href="#" class="mytag">#tag2</a> 
    <a href="#" class="mytag">#tag3</a>
  </div>
  <button id="Send">Send</button>
</div>
```

And the current jQuery is :

```
$(document).on("click","mytag", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var text_box = $('.message-content-box');
    var space = ' '
    if(text_box.val().length == 0) {
        space = ''
    }
    var hashtag = $(this).text()

    //If already selected
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected-mytag")){
        //Remove Selected class
        $(this).removeClass("selected-mytag");

        //Removes hashtag from text box
        text_box.val(text_box.val().replace(hashtag, ""));
    } else { //If not selected
        //Add selected class
        $(this).addClass("selected-mytag");
        //Add hashtag to text box
        text_box.val(text_box.val() + space + $(this).text());
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code as it currently is doesn't work. It's very hard to work out how it might need changing if the functionality doesn't match your description.;

Comment: Sorry, didn't input everything correctly. I have edited it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code worked for me:

```
$('.mytag').on("click", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var text_box = $('#ReplyBox');
    var space = ' ';
    if(text_box.val().length == 0) {
        space = '';
    }
    var hashtag = $(this).text();

    //If already selected
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected-sticky-hashtag")){
        //Remove Selected class
        $(this).removeClass("selected-sticky-hashtag");

        //Removes hashtag from text box
        text_box.val(text_box.val().replace(hashtag, ""));
    } else { //If not selected
        //Add selected class
        $(this).addClass("selected-sticky-hashtag");
        //Add hashtag to text box
        text_box.val(text_box.val() + space + $(this).text());
    }
});
$('#ReplyBox').on('keypress paste textInput input', function(){
    $('.selected-sticky-hashtag').each(function(){
        if($('#ReplyBox').val().indexOf($(this).text()) == -1)
            $(this).removeClass("selected-sticky-hashtag");
    });
});
```

What I am doing here, is to check on every change of the input value, if all active Tags are actually contained in the inputs value. I adjusted some of the selectors, because the code you provided didn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$( "textarea:contains(hashtag)").hasClass("selected-mytag"));
```